# Android - Video Image is cut from the right side in GLSurfaceView

Tags: android, android-layout, layout, opengl-es, glsurfaceview

I am using a `GLSurfaceView` to render camera data as video which is shown in the device screen. I am taking preview from camera and render that preview on my GLSurfaceView. That part works fine. My `GLSurfaceView` is added as a child of `FrameLayout`. User can double tap on that `FrameLayout`. In double tap, i make the image fullScreen on and off. There is the problem i am facing . I am uploading some image to better description of the problem. The first image is showing normal mode , it works fine. It is a 352*288 size image fitted with screen by filling width as MATCH_PARENT and Height is calculated with `SCREEN_WIDTH*(Aspect_Ratio)` . On Double Tap i make full screen. The calculation is i fill the Height as `MATCH_PARENT` and calculate the width as `SCREEN_WIDTH*ASPECT_RATIO` of Image. All are done by changing the width and height of `GLSUrfaceView` with `ViewGroup.LayoutParams`. But the problem is image is made big and it is cut from the right side only. I wanted the image to be cut equal in all side so the image real image center can be placed at the display center. On the third image i showed what i wanted. I don't know how to do that . Any help will be appreciable. Thank in advance [image: Normal Mode] 
[image: Full Screen Mode]

[image: What i need with Detail Scenario]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had figured out the problem. Android by default start showing image from the left edge of the screen. As my image was larger than the screen so the exceeded part got out of the screen from right side. Solution is calculate the width or height difference and then add a margin on left side (for width) or top (height)

```
ViewGroup.MarginLayoutParams marginLayoutParams = (ViewGroup.MarginLayoutParams) getLayoutParams();

if (CallConstants.isFullScreenMode) {
    if (layoutParams.width < displayWidth || layoutParams.height<displayHeight) {
        marginLayoutParams.setMargins(0, 0, 0, 0);
        setLayoutParams(marginLayoutParams);
        return;
    }
    int margin;
    if (mContext.getResources().getConfiguration().orientation == Configuration.ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT) {
        margin = (-(int) ((layoutParams.width - displayWidth) / 2));
        marginLayoutParams.setMargins(margin, 0, 0, 0);
    } else {
        margin = (-1 * (int) ((layoutParams.height - displayHeight) / 2));
        marginLayoutParams.setMargins(0, margin, 0, 0);
    }
} else {
    marginLayoutParams.setMargins(0, 0, 0, 0);
}

setLayoutParams(marginLayoutParams);
```